# MySQL One 4GB Table or 80 Small Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 80 books for Quran Explanation, some books are 230MB size and some are 1MB only the reset in between these two sizes, I mean, there is 2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 200MB. The database is only one table very simple like this:

```
Books (
    id      int primary key auto increment,
    book    int,
    chapter int,
    verse   int,
    explanation MEDIUMTEXT
);
```

The database will be queried and used only to display one entry at a time on a web page, the explanation of one verse in one chapter in one book, currently no search functions needed or will be required on the database.

The 80 books currently in text files about 3.5GB. I expect to become about 4GB in MySQL tables and all text is Arabic UTF8.

The number of rows in each book is fixed 6236, it is the number of Quran verses.
So the total table rows will be 80*6236 = 498,880 rows.

My question, should I just use one big data MySQL table for all 80 books, or put each single book in a single table. I do not need to access more than one book at the same time.

I have a dedicated server for this website with good hardware 128G RAM 512 SSD and 6 Cores/ 12 Processors CPU.

I explained the purpose in details because I know similar topics discussed but this is a very specific purpose.

Comment: You should use one table if they all have the same data structure.  You can use indexes and partitions for performance.

Comment: One table is always better if all the rows have the same columns.  There are many ways you can optimize a table that you can't do if data is multiple tables

Comment: @Hogan the table will have only one big text field, all other fields are just Integer, can you explain how to optimize such table or should I post this as another question?.

Comment: Your database (3.5 GB) is small compared to the size of your server (128 GB RAM). It will most likely be fully cached. And, yes, use a single table, with an index on (book, chapter, verse).

Comment: @Hogan web site visitors will browse the content one Table row entry at the same time, I mean within one book, within one chapter, will display the explanation of one verse.

Comment: Exactly, in order to get the data for that book, chapter and verse you will do a query against the DB -- if you have an index it will be faster.

Comment: I just added more information about total rows will be 498,880 rows.

Comment: A 'book' is just plain text, right? It seems unlikely that plain text would be anywhere near 230MB, so what else is going on here?

Comment: @Strawberry yes the book is 230MB each book is 6236 Verse and some single verse explanation text is 220 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one table if they all have the same data structure. You can use indexes and partitions for performance. – Gordon Linoff

In order to get the data for [specific] book, chapter and verse you will do a query against the DB -- if you have an index it will be faster. – Hogan

Comment: Yes both comments convinced me to use one table for the entire 80 books and I know about adding table indexes, but do not know about partitions, can you explain?